# Type mismatch: cannot convert from DataProvider to Annotation

Tags: java, selenium, testng, dataprovider

I am receiving a error of

> 'Type mismatch: 
>    cannot convert from DataProvider to Annotation' error for @DataProvider (@line 19)

Any help would be appreciated

```
package parameterization;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProvider 
{
    //This test method declares that its data should be supplied by the Data Provider
        // "getdata" is the function name which is passing the data
           // Number of columns should match the number of input parameters
        @Test(dataProvider="getData")
        public void setData(String username, String password)
        {
            System.out.println("you have provided username as::"+username);
            System.out.println("you have provided password as::"+password);
        }

        @DataProvider(name="getData")
        public Object[][] getData()
        {
        //Rows - Number of times your test has to be repeated.
        //Columns - Number of parameters in test data.
        Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];

        // 1st row
        data[0][0] ="sampleuser1";
        data[0][1] = "abcdef";

        // 2nd row
        data[1][0] ="testuser2";
        data[1][1] = "zxcvb";

        // 3rd row
        data[2][0] ="guestuser3";
        data[2][1] = "pass123";

        return data;
        }   
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Weird the same code works fine for me. What testng version are you using.

Comment: @MadisKangro check the name of your class. It should be exactly "DataProvider".

Answer (score 4):

Your class name is `DataProvider` and it hides your import `import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider`.

In line with error you think you use later, but actually use former.

Solution: Either rename your class or use FQN in annatation (`@org.testng.annotations.DataProvider(name="getData")`).